# Python iterate over two lists skipping some elements

Tags: python, iterator

I want to iterate over two lists, say:

```
alist = ['a_1', 'a_2', 'a_2', 'a_3', 'a_4']
blist = ['b_1', 'b_2', 'b_4']
```

The main issue is, sometimes I want to skip an element, so that zip and itertools.izip will not work as is. I would love to just do an izip and then next, like so:

```
for a,b in itertools.izip(alist,blist):
    asplit = a.split("_")
    bsplit = b.split("_")
    if asplit[len(asplit) -1] < bsplit[len(bsplit) -1]:
        next(a)
```

This example is minimal to show the behavior intended, I know it is not symmetric for a and b and will only skip once, but the principle is there. This will not work unfortunately, since the variable a is just the value, and not the iterator, so I get a type error:

```
TypeError: str object is not an iterator
```

I might be biased by thinking of stl iterators (C++), but there must be a python way to do this. Any help would be appreciated!

**edit:**

It seems I should have specified the behavior more. If at the end of the loop (after the `if ...` statement, i have

```
print a, b
```

Then I would expect the output:

```
a_1 b_1
a_2 b_2
a_3 b_4
```

I thought it was clear, but I chose the lists poorly for this, since that output seems to be unclear. If I had a `while asplit < bsplit` instead, which would be the more intuitive way, then I should expect

```
a_1 b_1
a_2 b_2
a_4 b_4
```

Comment: Why not keep track of current indexes for each list and then iterate the classic, yet verbose, way?

Comment: What you want to do with `next(a)`?

Comment: Use `asplit[-1]` instead of `asplit[len(asplit) -1]`, it's the same, but more readable.

Comment: Slightly off topic. I just wonder if you don't need a while (asplit < bsplit) rather then an if.

Comment: the `next(a)` would skip the current item and would give me the next element in the list.

Comment: (with first edit) Are you sure you want to output a_3 b_3 while there is no b_3 in your blist ?

Comment: @DainDawarf of course not. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Following your edit: If you do not want something symmetric, then you might want to not iterate on both list in a single foreach instruction:

```
for b in blist:
    for a in alist:
        asplit = a.split("_")
        bsplit = b.split("_")
        if asplit[-1]< bsplit[-1]:
            continue
        else:
            break
    print a, b
```

output:

```
a_1 b_1
a_2 b_2
a_4 b_4
```

Comment: that looks almost like I what I need. I edited the problem to better explain the behavior I want. The problem with this way is that it would skip, but the next iteration, not the current one. If I include the `print` statements from the edit here, then I cannot get the desired output, because I only have the value for the wrong ones